# Snapping while dragging a view

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm using android's drag and drop api. I want my view to move in chunks i.e. the movement should not be continuous. Say the unit is 50 pixels. So I would want my view to move every 50th pixel and not in between.

There is a lot of flickering while dragging when I do it the following way. (Well not just the flickering, the whole thing just doesn't work the way I expect it to)

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
            if(event.getX() > view.getX()){
                view.setX(view.getX() + 50);
            } else if (event.getX() < view.getX()){
                view.setX(view.getX() - 50);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

This code should work fine:

```
    final int SIZE = 50;
    View view;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                setX(event.getX()/SIZE);
                setY(event.getY()/SIZE);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```